# Create a python executable shortcut - path issue

Tags: python, path, ide, pyinstaller, shortcut

I created an executable with pyinstaller. The file is in the directory `Build` and I need to have several shortcuts of this .exe in many different directories. The problem is, my program uses an Excel table which will be accessed through a relative path. So when I use a shortcut of my .exe, the Excel table can't be found because the relative path works for the original .exe but not for the shortcut.

How can I access the Excel table?

Comment: What OS are you using? On Windows, shortcuts have an optional "Start in:" property which is the directory path that will be made the current working directory before starting the target executable. Regardless of the OS, regular Python code can use the current value of `__file__` to determine the script's directory. There is probably an equivalent when running a pyinstaller "compiled" script — check the documentation.

Comment: im on windows, thank you i will check this !

Comment: From the pyinstaller [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#using-file) I googled, it looks like the equivalent to `__file__` is `sys._MEIPASS`.